# Play Scala JSON: combine properties

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have the following case class:

`case class User(name: String)`.

I am trying to implement a JSON `Reads` converter for it, so I can do the following:

`val user = userJson.validate[User]`

… but the incoming JSON has slightly different structure:

`{ "firstName": "Bob", "lastName": "Dylan" }`.

How can I implement my JSON `Reads` converter to combine the JSON fields `firstName` and `lastName` into a `name` property on my class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
  implicit val userReads: Reads[User] = 
      for {
        first <- (__ \ "firstName").read[String]
        last <- (__ \ "lastName").read[String]
      } yield User(s"$first $last")
```

**EDIT**
*Without using a for comprehension*

```
implicit val userReads = 
  { 
    (__ \ "firstName").read[String] and 
    (__ \ "lastName"
  }.read[String] ).tupled.map(t => User(s"${t._1} ${t._2}"))
```

Bringing `userReads` in scope where you want to use it will let you parse the JSON you provided.

`Reads` is essentially a function from `JsValue` to `JsResult`, meaning `userReads` represents a function from `JsValue -> JsResult`. Within the function, it first inspects the provided JSON & tries to read out a property named "firstName" from the current JSON path (`__` is shorthand for this). `\` indicates that the field its looking for is one level beneath the root, and `read[String]` means the value associated with the "firstName" key should be read as a string. Same follows for "lastName".

**Edit**
In the version without the for comprehension, it first creates an intermediary object `FunctionalBuilder[Reads]#CanBuild[String, String]`, which is a complicated way of saying it reads two distinct strings from the Json. Next it converts that complex object into a `Reads[(String, String)]` by way of `tupled`. Finally it maps the pair of strings into a `User`.

Were you to try validating some JSON without "firstName" & "lastName", this will fail with a validation error for a missing path.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without a `for`? I currently have a combinator that looks like this: `val userReads: Reads[User] = (
    (__ \ "name").read[String] and
    (__ \ "age").read[String]
)(User.apply _)`

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure if it would be better to have a class for validating the user JSON, and a separate class with the data structured to suit my preferences. Is the above use case abusing JSON Reads for something they are not designed for?